# I want to know about command in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, command, fortran

```
FC= ifort

FCFLAGS=-O2 -r8 -openmp -mcmodel=large -extend-source -shared-intel -I$(HOME)/usr/include

LDFLAGS=-L$(HOME)/usr/lib -lfftw3 -lm

TARGET=Project

Project: a.o b.o c.o d.o 

#
all : $(TARGET)

%: %.o

    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.f90

    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<

all : $(TARGET)

clean :

    rm *.o
```

when I studied makefile, there is no information for

```
#
all : $(TARGET)
```

and function of `%` and `$^`. I wanna check about these things. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`all` is a target (repeated twice in that makefile for no reason). So is `clean`. Targets are how make works. See [Rule Example](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Example).

`$^` is one of the [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) available for use in target recipes.

`%` is a wildcard used in some make [functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) and in [Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules).